# Keras - Get mode of 2 one hot arrays

Tags: python, keras, tensor

I am building a simple model that takes in 2 one hot arrays (predictions) and gets the mode of the predictions.

for example if we had 2 arrays: [0,1] and [0,1] our mode should be class [0,1]
another example: [1,0][1,0][0,1] should be class [1,0]

I have this so far:

```
def mode(inputs):
    vals = [np.where(x==1)[0][0] for x in inputs]
    return max(set(vals), key=vals.count)


img_in = np.array([[0,1]])
txt_in = np.array([[1,0]])

img_input = Input((2,), name='image_input')
txt_input = Input((2,), name='text_input')
img_input = Reshape((2,))(img_input)
txt_input = Reshape((2,))(txt_input)

x = Lambda(mode)([img_input, txt_input])


model = Model(inputs=[img_input, txt_input], outputs=[x])
```

How can I get the mode of the vectors?

**EDIT:**

I can do something like this:

```
def mode(inputs):
    s = K.sum(inputs, axis=0)
    s = K.argmax(s)
    return s
```

But I get an error

```
TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int64 of argument 'x'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
def mode(inputs):
    s = K.sum(inputs, axis=0)
    s = K.one_hot(K.argmax(s), K.shape(s)[0])
    return s
```